# Equivalent of "ssh-keyscan -H" in Solaris 10/11

Tags: perl, solaris

I'm creating a Perl program that adds the specified host in root's known_hosts file. The program works in AIX and Linux, but not in Solaris and sadly, I can't find its equivalent command.

Sample line:

```
system("ssh-keyscan -H www.myserver.domain >> /.ssh/known_hosts");
```

Output:

> ssh-keyscan: illegal option -- H
>   Usage: ssh-keyscan [-v46] [-p port] [-T timeout] [-f file]
>                      [host | addrlist namelist] [...]

**Update 1:**

I tried the following command but it still asks for authenticity:

```
system("ssh-keyscan -t rsa www.myserver.domain >> /.ssh/known_hosts");
```

**Update 2:**
Output outside Perl:

```
# ssh-keyscan -t rsa www.myserver.domain >> /.ssh/test123.text 
# www.myserver.domain SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3  
# less test123.text
# www.myserver.domain ssh-rsa KEY  
# ssh www.myserver.domain
# The authenticity of host 'www.myserver.domain (IP)' can't be established. RSA key fingerprint is FINGERPRINT. Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Comment: What's the version of `ssh-keyscan` you're using on Solaris?

Comment: How do I find out the version of ssh-keyscan?

Comment: Can't tell, doesn't appear to display a version.

Comment: If you are root (as appears) and your homedir is in fact the rootdir, look at `/.ssh/known_hosts` and make sure a line for the desired host is in there, then try `ssh -v $hostname` and look at the logged output.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the man page for ssh-keyscan on Solaris 10/11 doesn't look to support that switch.

*Reference: [ssh-keyscan man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/ssh-keyscan-1.html)*

```
ssh-keyscan [-v46] [-p port] [-T timeout] [-t type] 
     [-f file] [-] [host... | addrlist namelist] [...]
```

I think you can just do `ssh-keyscan <hostname>` however to retrieve the keys and then write them to your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. This will still work but just won't put all the names that the host goes by on a single line like this:

```
hostname1, hostname1.fqdn.com .....
```

So you might have some cleanup work to do on the resulting `known_hosts` file.

#### Host authenticity

If you find you're encountering this issue which amounts to a catch 22, where you cannot scan a host that's not yet present in your `known_hosts` file:

> The authenticity of host 'www.myserver.domain (IP)' can't be established. RSA key fingerprint is FINGERPRINT. Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

You can work around this issue by temporarily disabling `StrictHostKeyChecking`:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
...
StrictHostKeyChecking no
...
```

Then do your `keyscan <host> ...` command again. Once you're complete, be sure to remove the `StrictHostKeyChecking` from your `~/.ssh/config`.

#### References

- [ssh_config man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)

Comment: @Shan - what happens if you say `y` at that prompt?

Comment: host will be added to the list of known_hosts (not recommended; I need to automate this)

Comment: @Shan - see updates.